# How to make React-Material UI data grid to render rows using alternate shades?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am evaluating React-Material grid for my customer. One of the key feedback was the absence of alternate shading of rows, which impacts user experience.

https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/#mit-version

Is this possible?

### Actual

[image]

### Desired

[image]

thank you,

Sau

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### MUI5 DataGrid Striping

[For MUI5](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/style/#striped-rows), as pointed out by keemor in the comments, you can use `indexRelativeToCurrentPage` parameter of the `getRowClassName` prop argument. For compatibility with the original undocumented Mui-even/Mui-odd class names, you can return those class names via this prop as below:

```
<DataGrid
  loading={loading}
  {...data}
  getRowClassName={(params) =>
    params.indexRelativeToCurrentPage % 2 === 0 ? 'Mui-even' : 'Mui-odd'
  }
/>
```

The `indexRelativeToCurrentPage` value does reset between pages, so the first item in page one will be even along with the first item in page 2, no matter how many items there are per page.

The `:nth-child` selectors mentioned in the MUI4 section is only a viable solution if you turn off [data virtualization](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/virtualization/) which is active by default. If you tried to use it with virtualization, then you'll end up with a strobe effect as you scroll due to the removal of elements outside the viewport.

---

### MUI4 DataGrid Striping

It's pretty simple to add in via a CSS selector.

If you add a selector for the odd rows `.Mui-odd`, then you can set the color of the background and make it striped. You could use `.Mui-even` instead for the other half.

```
.MuiDataGrid-row.Mui-odd {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

Here's a [working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-plosc?file=/styles.css)

If you wanted to use `:nth-child`, then you'd need `:nth-child(even)` for the same set of rows as .Mui-odd, though .Mui-odd keeps up it's ordering between pages, where the psuedo selector doesn't.

```
.MuiDataGrid-row:nth-child(even){
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

Comment: Would you know why this CSS class is missing from the official documentation page of Material UI data grid page?
https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/#css

Thank you

Comment: I have no idea why they don't have that class in the documentation. Perhaps it's better to use an `nth-child` selector instead if the css class is undocumented. You could also put in an issue or PR to the github repo to get it documented.

Comment: This is how you can do it for DataGrid in MUI5 https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/style/#striped-rows

Answer (score 3):

Using this solution you can make it dynamic with light/dark modes and also preserve mouse hover effects.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
  ({
    root: {
      '& .MuiDataGrid-row.Mui-even:not(:hover)': {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.type === 'light' ? 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)' : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04)',
      },
    },
  }),
);
```

Comment: Hey Paito, your example does notn seem to work, the css though, does.

Comment: Did you wrap your DataGrid with something like `<div className={classes.root}>`?

Comment: No, i did not. Thanks.

Comment: Might be even better to use the `theme.palette.secondary[300]` colors to stick with the theme.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in MUI v5 - TypeScript.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  ({
    root: {
      '& .MuiDataGrid-row:nth-child(odd)': {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? theme.palette.secondary[300] : theme.palette.secondary[900]
      },
    },
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

See the official `StripedDataGrid` component [example](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/style/#striped-rows).